Car brake pedal feels like pushed back
I was driving in maruti Suzuki Brezza car it was heavily raining and when I brake. Sometimes it feels like brake pedal is pushed by obstacle or like stone just pushing brake pedal back to normal position.Why is that? First time I am feeling this. Do I need to show to dealer?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does your car have anti-lock brakes?

Does your Brezza have antilock braking? ABS relies on a driver standing on the brake pedal in emergency braking or in foul weather conditions when tire traction is lost while braking; abs takes over braking to prevent any wheel from locking up and allow steering to a stop or avoid an impending crash. When abs activates, there will be a high speed vibration from the abs motor generating brake pressure while the abs unit closes off brake pedal input while electronics controls braking. Typical descriptions of abs activation is the 'foot massage' feedback from the abs unit and normal.

Yes it has antilock bracking
